# Как убрать лишние цифры в целом числе?

Tags: python-3.x, int

На входе числа с лишними восемью нулями в конце.
Пример числа 4900000000.
На выходе не обходимо получить 49.
Как добиться такого результата?

Comment: Поделить на 100000000

Comment: это гениально. спасибо!

Comment: Всё гениальное просто. Зачем усложнять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обычным перебором пока в конце числа не закончатся нули делим на 10:

```
def delete_zeros(value: int):
    while not value % 10:
        value //= 10
    return value
print(delete_zeros(400900000000))
```

Вывод

```
4009
```

Comment: классное решение, спасибо